# Romance languages - "to mean" as "to want to say"

Tags: romance-languages, evolution

I have noticed this phenomenon in quite a few Romance languages, that the verb "to mean" can also be conveyed by the phrase "to want to say", regardless of the origin of the verb "to want".

For example:

```
(Language): (verb meaning "to mean") | (phrase meaning "to want to say")
French:                    signifier | vouloir dire
Spanish:                  significar | querer decir
Portuguese:               significar | querer dizer
Catalan:                  significar | voler dir    (credits to fedorqui)
Italian:                 significare | voler dire
Northern Sardinian:      significare | quérrer narrare/nàrrere
Southern Sardinian:       significai | bòllir nài
```

As shown above, "querer" comes from the Latin verb "QVAERERE" while "vouloir" comes from the Latin verb "VELLE".

Am I correct to deduce then, that this phenomenon does not have a Latin origin?

Answers stating more cognates are also welcome.

Comment: Same in Catalan: `significar | voler dir`

Comment: @fedorqui Gràcies, afegit.

Comment: The verb *to mean* exists in Germanic languages, but not in Romance ones. In any case, its existence is a luxury rather than a necessity. In its absence, the most natural ways of conveying the same expression is by using one of the verbs *want / wish / desire*, followed by *say*.

Comment: Worth noting that the same periphrasis also exists in Dutch (*willen zeggen*) and German (*sagen wollen*).

Comment: None the Romance verbs from _significare_ take a human subject, any more than _signify_ does in modern English. To indicate a human subject, one must use a different construction, which undoubtedly was developed early in Romance history, like many other features.

Comment: @jlawler that's an interesting observation that I didn't think about